# Kivy 2.3.0: AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasKivyAgg' object has no attribute 'resize_event'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm attempting to create a basic graph within my Kivy application, but I'm encountering difficulties when using **FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())** to plot it but I keep getting **AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasKivyAgg' object has no attribute 'resize_event'**. Despite searching extensively and watching tutorials, I haven't found any solutions to this issue. It appears that others can plot successfully using FigureCanvasKivyAgg, but I'm using Kivy 2.3.0, and I haven't been able to find documentation that addresses my specific problem.

This is example app that I'm using to add plots to Kivy App

matty.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.clock import Clock


#Graphical Imports
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 14, 7, 20, 11]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.xlabel("x axis")

class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Graph(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))

    def save(self):
        pass

class Project(BoxLayout):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("matty.kv")

class TestApp(MDApp):
    title = "Kivy Project"

    def build(self, **kwargs):
        return Project()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

matty.kv

```
#:kivy 2.3.0
<Project>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
   
    SomeMenu_ActionBar:
        id: ActionBar

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        WelcomeScreen:
        FirstScreen:
        SecondScreen:
            Graph:
                id: graph_screen

<SomeMenu_ActionBar@ActionBar>:

    ActionView:
        id: ActionView

        HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious:

        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: "spinner"
            text: "Jump to Screen"

            ActionButton:
                text: "Welcome Screen"
                on_release:
                    app.root.ids.sm.current = 'welcome'
                    app.root.ids.sm.transition.direction = "right"
            ActionButton:
                text: "First Screen"
                on_release:
                    app.root.ids.sm.current = 'first'
                    app.root.ids.sm.transition.direction = "left"
            ActionButton:
                text: "Second Screen"
                on_release:
                    app.root.ids.sm.current = 'second'
                    app.root.ids.sm.transition.direction = "left"
       
        ActionGroup:
            id: App_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'App'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Settings'
                on_press: app.open_settings()
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_press: app.get_running_app().stop()
       
        ActionGroup:
            id: File_ActionGroup
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'File'

            ActionButton:
                text: 'Open'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Save'
       
        ActionButton:
            text: 'Back to Main Menu'
            on_release:
                app.root.ids.sm.current = 'welcome'
                app.root.ids.sm.transition.direction = "right"

<HiddenIcon_ActionPrevious@ActionPrevious>:
    title: ''
    with_previous: False
    app_icon: ''
    app_icon_width: 0
    app_icon_height: 0
    size_hint_x: None
    width: len(self.title)*10

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcome'
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome Screen'
        font_size: sp(50)

<FirstScreen>:
    id: first
    name: 'first'
    Label:
        text: 'First Screen'

<SecondScreen>:
    id: second
    name: 'second'
    Graph:
        id: graph_screen
<Graph>:
    id: boxgraph
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .9
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
       
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        TextInput:
            id: name
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Save"
            on_release: root.save()
```

Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\Application\Classes\matty.py", line 58, in <module>
     TestApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 956, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 379, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 733, in tick
     self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\\_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 97, in do_layout
     c.size = c_w, c_h
     ^^^^^^
   File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 1478, in kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.set
   File "kivy\\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property._dispatch
   File "kivy\\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\\_event.pyx", line 1213, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\alisu\OneDrive - UWE Bristol\UWE Bristol & Stuff\3rd Year UWE\Digital Systems\Alistana Fitness & Nutrition Tracker\AFNT-Digital-Systems-Project\AFNT\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\garden\matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 1233, in _on_size_changed
     self.resize_event()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasKivyAgg' object has no attribute 'resize_event'
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug that was recently fixed, but you need to install the updated kivy garden matplotlib like this:

```
python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy-garden/matplotlib/archive/master.zip
```

See the [github source](https://github.com/kivy-garden/matplotlib).

And you will need to change your import from `kivy.garden` to `kivy_garden`.